# Derivatives: How to find the equation of tangent line $f(x)=\frac{2}{x}-\frac{3}{x^2}$ at (1,-1)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can you go step by step as to how you found the answer? Thank you!!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What is the purpose of this problem? Are you required to find the derivative using the definition or applying formula?

Comment: He would like a step by step explanation of how to solve the problem. Perhaps he does not know where to start, and that is why there is no supplemental info about what he has tried. Please stop needlessly penalizing people for asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line has the equation (in slope-intercept form) $y = mx +b$ where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the y-intercept. If we have the slope $m$ and a point on the line, we can substitute and solve for the y-intercept, $b$. The slope of a line tangent to the curve of $f$ at point $P_0 = (x_0, y_0)$ is equal to the derivative of $f$ at $P_0$, or $\frac{df}{fx} (x_0, y_0)$. So, first lets find the derivative of $f$ as follows...

Given $$f(x) = \frac{2}{x} - \frac{3}{x^2} = 2x^{-1} - 3x^{-2}$$

The derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ is given by

$$ \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} [2x^{-1} - 3x^{-2}]$$

By the sum/difference rule of derivatives we have

$$= \frac{d}{dx} 2x^{-1} - \frac{d}{dx} 3x^{-2}$$

By the constant multiple rule of derivatives we have

$$= 2 \frac{d}{dx} x^{-1} - 3 \frac{d}{dx} x^{-2}$$

By the power rule of derivatives we have

$$= 2 (-1)x^{-2} - 3(-2)x^{-3}$$

and we finish with basic algebra

$$= \frac{-2}{x^2} + \frac{6}{x^3}$$

Hence,

$$ \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \frac{-2}{x^2} + \frac{6}{x^3}$$

Now that we have the function that returns derivatives (i.e. the slopes of lines tangent to our curve $f$), we find the derivative of $f$ at our point $(1,-1)$, or $\frac{df}{fx} (1,-1)$ given by

$$\frac{df}{fx} (1, -1) = \frac{-2}{(1)^2} + \frac{6}{(1)^3} = -2+6 =4$$

Now that we have the slope of the tangent line at $(1,-1)$, which is $4$, and a point on the line, or $(1,-1)$, we substitute the ingredients into our equation for a line and solve for the y-intercept, $b$.

$y=mx+b$

$\Leftrightarrow -1 = 4(1) + b $

$\Leftrightarrow -1=4+b $

$\Leftrightarrow b=-5$

Now we that have the y-intercept, $b=-5$, we substitute back into the equation of our line, and we have our answer.

$y=4x-5$

Comment: but now say that there was a number in front of that entire equation such as 3x(18x^4+13/x+1)?? would it essentially be the same concept?

Comment: In that case, you would end up using the rules outlined above, but in addition you would also have to use either the product rule or the quotient rule of derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

First use the addition rule to separate $\frac{2}{x}$ and $\frac{-3}{x^2}$.

Then use quotient rule for both:
$\frac{-2}{x^2}$ and $\frac{6x}{x^4}$

Put them together to get:

$\frac{-2}{x^2}+ \frac{6}{x^3}$

I would go into more details gladly if you tell me what you need help with by showing your work